# SQL: Decimal precision as specified by user

Tags: sql-server

In C#, the `decimal` type 'remembers' the precision of the original number:

```
decimal.Parse("090,12300").ToString() == "90,12300"
decimal.Parse("090,123").ToString() == "90,123"
decimal.Parse("090,0").ToString() == "90,0"
decimal.Parse("90").ToString() == "90"
```

For business reasons (*), this precision is important for us, so we want persist this in the database (SqlServer). Is there an SQL-datatype (except varchar) that behaves in the same way as the c# `decimal`?

(*) The users want to see the exact number as entered in the application. For example: some scales are more precise than others. This means that 12.5 has another meaning than 12.50 in this scenario.

Comment: In terms of value the 1st and 2nd decimals are exactly the same as are the 3rd and 4th. You can append as many 0s at the end of a decimal as you want, the value does not change. What is the reason that you want to also persist the 0's? The total number of possible places after the the seperator is the `scale` (not precision which is the total number of digits including the scale), in Sql Server you specify this for the column. See [decimal and numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

Comment: Clarified my scenario.

Comment: varchar is the only datatype that will do this. The numeric/decimal types (which are the same thing) won't preserve the initial number of decimal places entered. Another option would be to hold the value as a decimal/numeric and have another column for the precision.

Comment: I do not think its possible without using the data type `varchar` side by side or adding another column as `int` that keeps track of the entered scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two columns, one for the value itself, and second one for number of digits after point.

What you will need is a function that format your value to string, with padding zero until enough number of digit.

Comment: Since we're using NHibernate, we ended up using a custom UserType that translates a ```decimal``` .net type to two columns in the database.